# Linq query to check substring between a list and string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of strings and a string, and I want that if the string contains any of the string which is present in the list the system returns false. I am using following lambda expression:

```
 result = !(((string[])ro_operandVal).ToList<string>()).Any(x => x.ToString().ToUpper() == lo_operandVal.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Following is the dataset:

lo_operandVal = "ABC DEF GHI Post Office Box"
ro_operandVal is the list of strings with following elements:

1. Post Office Box
2. P.O. BOX

when I evaluate this expression it always returns true.

Comment: You say you want to find if the string *contains* any of the strings present in the list, but you're comparing using *equals*. Given your string isn't equal to any of them it doesn't seem too surprising you don't find a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the below linq - 
if any value in list found in string then it will return `false`, and if none of them found then it will return `true`.

```
var result = ro_operandVal.All(c=>lo_operandVal.IndexOf(c) < 0);
```

**Update**

both are object type and you know their exact type that they are `List<string>` and `string` you can type cast them.

```
var result = ((List<string>)ro_operandVal).All(c=>lo_operandVal.ToString().IndexOf(c) < 0);
```

Comment: I much prefer this approach. You might want to use the `IndexOf` overload that takes a `StringComparison` so you can ignore case (per the code in the question).

Comment: ro_operand and lo_operand are of object type

Comment: you can never mentioned this in your question.  Btw when you know there exact type that they are `List<string>` and another is `string` you can type cast them

Comment: http://rextester.com/OEJ33614 check it out, it should return true I guess

Comment: no,, you said in your question, if any exist then it should return `false`, so if you case `Ali` exist in string value and thats the reason it return `false`, instead of `Ali` type `Deepak`, it will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Contains()` to see if the text is contained within the list, instead of trying to match strings exactly using the equals operator.

```
 result = !(((string[])ro_operandVal).ToList<string>()).Any(x => x.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(lo_operandVal.ToString().ToUpper()));
```

Comment: No Problem, you can do it yourself by clicking the `edit` right under your answer... And you can also delete your old comments, so the post looks cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

Use contains as follows:

```
 result = !(((string[])ro_operandVal).ToList<string>()).Any(x => x.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(lo_operandVal.ToString().ToUpper()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code worked perfectly for me

```
  result = !(((string[])ro_operandVal).ToList<string>().Any(lo_operandVal.ToString().Contains));
```

for ignoring the case:

```
 result = !((((string[])ro_operandVal).ToList<string>().ConvertAll(d => d.ToUpper())).Any(lo_operandVal.ToString().ToUpper().Contains));
```