# Lambda statement for finding sub-string in a string from list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings:

1. This
2. Is
3. String
4. Find

and a string **"Find my String"** what I need now is a lambda statement to search that my string contains any of the string from the list.

Comment: There are a few ways of doing so but what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180205/linq-query-to-check-substring-between-a-list-and-string/43180450#43180450

Comment: Let us know what how you did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool contains = list.Any(yourString.Contains);
```

This is searching for substrings, so it doesn't compare "words".

Here is a version that ignores the case:

```
bool contains = list.Any(s => yourString.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: But that's going to do substring matching rather than just whole word matching.

Comment: @juharr: true, but OP hasn't mentioned that he needs to compare words(whatever that is). He said he wants to know if the string _contains_ any of the other strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Split()` your search expression and find on that like

```
var data =  "Find my String".Split(' ');
var result = your_list_string.Where(s => data.Contains(s));
```

Comment: are you sure questions with that low quality deserve a answer?

Comment: @Toshi, may be but that doesn't mean the answer has to be downvoted though it's a correct answer. There are many such example present in SO

Comment: stop feeding help vampires - if there are so many examples, make a duplicate vote

Comment: @Toshi, yeah and that's why another answer gets upvote ... grow up man

Comment: I didn't upvote the other answer

Comment: @Toshi You also didn't down vote it.

Comment: I agree with Toshi that we shouldn't answer this type of low effort questions, but it's not a reason to downvote a correct answer